# Combining SQL rows where column X values are equal but column Y values are different (need to be overriden)

Tags: mysql, sql, filtering

complete newbie in SQL here. I have an assignment where I was supposed to create a whole bunch of tables and then perform certain filtering among them. 
As seen from the picture, these are actually 2 distinct titles (from a larger table that has more of these) but each of them comes as a book, audio and video copy, hence why there are 3 rows for each distinct title.

Is there any way that I can scan through the multiple rows based on the Title and then return just a single row for each Title stating whether it's available as video and audio? So as long as in any 3 rows, the answer is yes in the "available_in_audio" or "available_in_video", that 'yes' will override the 'no' for any columns scanned before or after it.

For example for the 3 Harry Potter and the Chamber of Secrets rows, I just want a single row where "Available_in_Audio" is Yes and "Available_in_Video" is Yes.

[If both available_as_video and available_as_audio are "No", means it's a book, if available_as_audio is "Yes" means it's an audio copy and available_as_video means it's a video copy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tNKln.png)

Thank you so much and sorry for the long question!

Comment: You should *normalise* your schema, by splitting this table into two.

Comment: i support your comment about normalization @eggyal but saying splitting this table into two is normalization i do not support. Because normalization off the topicstarters data could require more then two tables.

Comment: That's fair comment, @RaymondNijland.

Comment: `GROUP BY` and `MAX` for the audio and video columns

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
SELECT Title, 
    CASE WHEN (MAX(CASE WHEN Available_in_Audio = 'Yes' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)) = 1 THEN 'Yes' ELSE 'No' END) AS Available_in_Audio,
    CASE WHEN (MAX(CASE WHEN Available_in_Video = 'Yes' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)) = 1 THEN 'Yes' ELSE 'No' END) AS Available_in_Video,
FROM <YourTable>
GROUP BY TITLE
```

Comment: I know i shouldn't comment "thanks", but thank you so much! It did successfully group them and it tallied with another parameter that I used to check. I will go and read up on cases now, thank you!

Comment: If it helped you consider marking my answer as answer. Thank you ;-)